# how to set the weekday in order email template magento 2.4

Tags: sales-order, magento2.4, order-email

how to set the weekday Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday etc in created_at_formatted in order email

**example: Placed on 23.06.2022, 12:00:19**

***to set***

***Placed on: Friday, 24.06.2022***

> {{trans 'Placed on %created_at'
> created_at=$created_at_formatted |raw}}

Answer (score 0):

You can create a observer to the event `email_order_set_template_vars_before`.

In the observer replace `created_at_formatted` in `transportObject` with your custom format

```
// use __constructor instead
$timezone = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
    ->get(\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface::class);
$locale   = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
    ->get(\Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface::class)
    ->getLocale();

$localeDate = $timezone->date(new \DateTime($order->getCreatedAt()), new \DateTimeZone('UTC')), $locale);

// you can get order and transportObject from observer
// like $observer->getEvent()->getData('order');

$transportObject->setData('created_at_formatted', $localeDate->format('l, d.m.Y'));
```